# How to solve 502 bad gate way in Elastic Beanstalk (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm a college student studying server.
I'm trying to distribute to node.js from elastic beanstalk, but 502 bad gate way keeps showing up.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4fei.png)

And the nginx.conf file is as follows.

```
user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    33282;

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    types_hash_bucket_size 128;

    log_format  main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    upstream node {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
        keepalive 1024;
    }

    server {
        listen        80 default_server;
        listen        [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://node;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
            proxy_read_timeout 600s;
            proxy_send_timeout 600s;

        }

        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        gzip                  off;
        gzip_comp_level       4;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/healthd.conf;
    }
}
```

And error.log is as follows

```
[error] 2214#2214: *29 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.2.130, server: , request: "GET /health HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/health", host: "10.0.2.231"
```

and index.js is as follows

```
import express from 'express';
import { specs } from './config/swagger.config.js';
import SwaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';

import { response } from './config/response.js';
import { BaseError } from './config/error.js';
import { status } from './config/response.status.js';
import { healthRoute } from './src/routes/health.route.js';

dotenv.config();    

const app = express();

// server setting - veiw, static, body-parser etc..
app.set('PORT', process.env.PORT || 3000)   
app.use(cors());                            
app.use(express.static('public'));          
app.use(express.json());                    
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false})); 

app.use('/api-docs', SwaggerUi.serve, SwaggerUi.setup(specs));

app.use('/health', healthRoute);

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(response(status.SUCCESS, "root!"));
})

// error handling
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const err = new BaseError(status.NOT_FOUND);
    next(err);
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    
    res.locals.message = err.message;   
    
    res.locals.error = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? err : {}; 
    console.error(err);
    res.status(err.data.status || status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send(response(err.data));
});

app.listen(app.get('PORT'), () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${app.get('PORT')}`);
});
```

and pakage.json is as follows

```
    {
  "name": "mission8",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "12",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node index.js",
    "start:dist": "webpack --mode production & node ./dist/main.js",
    "start": "node main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.2.0",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.5"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.22.19",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.6",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
    "swagger-cli": "^4.0.4",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.8",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

finally dev_deploy.yml follows

```
name: Node.js Dev CI/CD 

on:
  pull_request:      
    types: [ closed ] 
  workflow_dispatch: 

jobs:
  build:
    
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true && github.event.pull_request.base.ref == 'dev' 
    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: ['18.x']  
        
    steps: 
      
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3   

      
      - name: Set up Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'

      - name: Install Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci   

      - name: Run Build
        run: npm run build 

      
      - name: Generate deployment package
        run: |
          cp -R .platform dist
          cp package.json dist/package.json
          cp package-lock.json dist/package-lock.json
          cp Procfile dist/Procfile
          cd dist
          zip -r deploy.zip .
      
      
      - name: Get Zip Inside
        run: zipinfo -1 dist/deploy.zip

      
      - name: Get current time
        uses: 1466587594/get-current-time@v2
        id: current-time
        with:
          format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH-mm-ss
          utcOffset: "+09:00" 

  
      - name: Show Current Time
        run: echo "CurrentTime=${{steps.current-time.outputs.formattedTime}}"
        shell: bash 

      
      - name: Beanstalk Deploy
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v21
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{secrets.AWS_ACTION_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
          aws_secret_key: ${{secrets.AWS_ACTION_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
          application_name: Umc-dev
          environment_name: Umc-dev-env
          version_label: github-action-${{ steps.current-time.outputs.formattedTime }} 
          use_existing_version_if_available: true
          region: ap-northeast-2
          deployment_package: dist/deploy.zip
          wait_for_deployment: false 

      
      - name: Deployed!
        run: echo App deployed to ELB
```

I've also modified the port number, and I've tried to substitute the value myself. But it still shows up 502 bad gateway

Comment: would you include you're package.json and `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` with you're file structure too ?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I uploaded the code